# WIFIhotspot.MIkrotik+radius(ubuntu)+webserver(reg.ru)

Tags: mikrotik, hotspot, freeradius

Есть wifi с хотспотом.
Поднял сервер с freeradius 3. 
psswd login берет из mysql.

Все хорошо все работает. Захотелось сделать  ВНЕШНЮЮ страницу авторизации.

И вот тут тупик.
Я не знаю как заставить взаимодействовать внешнюю страницу index.php с радиусом и микротиком.

Answer (score 0):

Берем страничку rlogin.html

```
$(if http-status == 302)Hotspot login required$(endif)
$(if http-header == "Location")http://example.com/index.php?linklogin=$(link-login-only-esc)$(endif)
<html>
<head>
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/index.php/?linklogin=$(link-login-only-esc)">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

На вашем PHP лови `linklogin` в сессию. Как там авторизацию закончишь то передавай редирект на ссылку в переменной `linklogin` с параметрами GET `username` и `password`. В настройках хотспота убрать галочку chap.

Пароль передается в открытом виде и его можно поснифайть в открытой сети. Немного прикрыться можно chap: cоздаешь такую же страничку, но с переменными `$(chap-challenge)` и `$(chap-id)`. Редирект на неё, с неё обратно на пхп и уже на логин с chap.

А лучше настроить **https**.